# MySQL Select and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I have a table

```
id    ip
1     127.0.0.1
2     127.0.0.1
3     127.0.0.1
4     192.168.2.2
5     192.168.70.1
6     217.11.24.65
```

I need to get rows from 3 ips i.e. if i have limit 3 I must to get **1,2,3,4,5**

If Limit 2 - 1,2,3,4

i.e. limited by unique IPs

```
SELECT id FROM ips LIMIT 3 // returns 1,2,3 but i want 1,2,3,4,5
```

Sorry for bad english and thanks for understanding.

Comment: Limit doesnot work like this, use the querry like `Shedal` is sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM ips
WHERE ip IN (SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM ips ORDER BY id LIMIT 3)
```

As MySQL 5.5 doesn't yet support `LIMIT` inside of `ANY`, here's a simple workaround:

```
SELECT id
FROM ips
WHERE ip IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM ips ORDER BY id LIMIT 3) alias)
```

Comment: My version 5.5.23 and I getting an error. #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'